# cannot see row in datatable primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with java primefaces,

I have my xhtml as follows;

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{myProjects.projects}" sortMode="multiple" rows="25" paginator="true">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Dahil Olduğum Projeler
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column id="modelHeader" sortBy="#{projectsList.sector}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sektör" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{projectsList.sector}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="#{projectsList.projectName}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="İşin Adı" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{projectsList.projectName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="#{projectsList.startDate}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Başlangıç Tarihi" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{projectsList.startDate}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="#{projectsList.endDate}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Bitiş Tarihi" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{projectsList.endDate}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Son Durum" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{projectsList.lastStats}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

            </h:form>


        </p:layoutUnit>
```

And also I have my MyProjects java file:

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyProjects")
@SessionScoped
public class MyProjects implements Serializable {

    private List<ProjectsList> projects;

    public MyProjects(){
        projects=new ArrayList<ProjectsList>();
    projects.add(new ProjectsList("asd","asd","asd","asd","asd"));
    projects.add(new ProjectsList("asd","asd","123","123","123"));
    projects.add(new ProjectsList("asd","asd","123","123","123"));
    projects.add(new ProjectsList("asd","asd","123","123","123"));
} 

public List<ProjectsList> getProjects(){
    projects.get(0);



       return projects;
    }


}
```

When I want to see the rows in datatable I (for example here I have added 4 entries) I only see 4 rows without text in it.

How can I make the entries visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<h:outputText value="#{projectsList.sector}" />` should be `<h:outputText value="#{car.sector}" />` (and similar for all EL expression in your table. As defined in the "var" property of the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Data table variable `var="car"` did not used in column. it must be

```
<p:column sortBy="#{car.projectName}">
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value="İşin Adı" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{car.projectName}" />
</p:column>
```

Also `car` is not a proper variable here.  Name it like 
`var='project' value="#{myProjects.projects}"`